# Moving linear regression on google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a table with four columns:

`A`: date

`B`: values

`C`: projection

`D`: short-term projection

The first two are hardcoded values. We admit that dates go up, while values mostly go down. I used a linear regression and a simple division so that projection displays the estimated date when value would hit 0.

The linear regression is done thanks to this formula:

```
=LINEST($B$5:$B23;$A$5:$A23)
```

`5` being the first row in my table that contains valuable data.

If the regression is put in column `E` and `F`, projection is calculated by the following formula:

```
=-F23/E23
```

Column `D` is supposed to contain a projected date, but only dealing with the n last rows, and not since the beginning of my table. Assuming `n=15`, I  removed some dollar signs for the linear regression so that only the last 15 elements are considered:

```
=LINEST($B8:$B23;$A8:$A23)
```

I would like this 15 to be a variable that I put in a cell and that I can easily change. Is that possible without using scripting? I tried to use `INDIRECT`, but I could not make it work the way I wanted.

I guess that I would need something like `RANGE(A10;up;W17)` where `W17` is my `n` variable.

Answer (score -1):

##### How to select last N rows using the INDIRECT function

Imagine there's column `A` with an undetermined count of numeric rows, it is then possible to access the last `n` (specified in e.g. `$F$2` cell) rows using the following function:

```
INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("A", COUNT(A:A) - $F$2 + 1, ":A", COUNT(A:A)))
```

For example, if `A` has **10** rows and `$F$2` is **3**, the `CONCATENATE` function above will return `A8:A10`, and the `INDIRECT` function will return the respective range as if `A8:A10` range expression were hard-coded in the cell.

I tested it with `SUM` but it should also be possible to use this expression in the `LINEST` function required in the question:

```
=LINEST(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("A", COUNT(A:A) - $F$2 + 1, ":A", COUNT(A:A))))
```

However, if the reason to do a linear regression on the last **N** rows only is because the dates and values slopes change ever so slightly with time, it might be advisable to add more features (e.g. binary 1 or 0: `isWeekend`, `isWinter`, `isSummer`, `isAutumn`), use standard scaling and cross-validation sampling and train a model on the entire data rather than just the last **N** rows, it is likely that the resulting model will have better quality.

##### How to do linear regression with standard scaling in Google Sheets

1. Install [TableTorch add-on](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/tabletorch/347211125985) for Google Sheets.
2. Refresh your spreadsheet, click on the TableTorch icon on the right-side panel of Google Sheets.
3. Select your dataset's range and click the **Linear Regression** item on the main menu of TableTorch.
4. Click the **Fit model** button.
5. Click the **Insert prediction column** button, it will create a column with a simple arithmetic formula that is readily usable for the new data.

Standard scaling is **on** by default for linear regressions done by TableTorch and cross-validation can be enabled in the sampling options, it usually improves robustness of the model.

P.S. I am the author of the mentioned add-on and will be glad to hear any feedback.